# Create a Hyperlink from a link that is in a field

Tags: email, lightning-templates

I'm trying to create a hyperlink in an email template.  The hyperlink is from a field and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hello, it should do it if you wrap in an <a> tag ?

Comment: otherwise you could create a formula field which applies the Hyperlink function to your initial field, and then add the formula field inside the email template